# How to Remove Random Line Breaks in Table to XML File in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json, xml

I have a table with 270,000 rows and I wish to export two of the columns into XML.

I use

```
SELECT 
    [WordItem] as w, [Definition] as d
FROM 
    [dbo].[Dictionary]
FOR XML Path('Word')
```

to create the XML file, but when I "Save As", the file has random line breaks and which splits some of the XML tags.

Is there a way to fix or avoid this? I want to then convert the XML file to JSON and it's proving difficult because of this (Any advice on how to convert easily convert a large XML file to JSON is welcome too!)

Comment: Not everything is clear to me: You ran this query an you get a correct XML result, right? Where do run this (SQL Server Management Studio, any application, own code...)? How do you call this? Where is your result written to? Which file (and where) are you trying to save with "Save As"? Please provide more details!

Comment: Btw: SQL Server 2016 should include native support for JSON...

Comment: I was able to save the xml file and I don't see any issues,are you saying that your table itself has line breaks

Comment: @Shnugo This query was performed in SQL-Server Management Studio and file was saved from the Results to Grid output within it. Unfortunately my computers at work don't have Windows 8 (Using Windows 7), meaning I'm unable to install SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @Powellellogram In this case I'd assume, that your data entries contain line breaks. You might repeat your query with a `REPLACE(REPLACE(WordItem,CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(13),' ')` (the same with `Definition`), or you try the query I posted as answer.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Nope, the XML file that SQL Server Management Studio produces seems to break the lines on its own. I'm saving the file as .txt, not sure if that's an issue though

Comment: @Shnugo That doesn't really explain why some of the line breaks occur within XML Tags (<Word> can turn to <Wo rd> even when the XML filed is Linarized)

Comment: @Powellellogram Are you dealing with special characters, unicode... I've never seen this and I do a lot with SQL Server and XML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meanwhile - as long as SQL Server hasn't got native JSON support - you might try it like this:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT '{\n"root": {\n"Word": [' + 

    STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ',\n{\n"w": "' +  [WordItem] + '",\n"d": "' + [Definition] + '"\n}'
    FROM [dbo].[Dictionary]
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')

    + '\n]\n}\n}'
);
SELECT REPLACE(@json,'\n',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10));
```

If the generated string is bigger than 8192 characters you won't be able to see the full string in SSMS. There is a trick:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@json,'\n',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
FOR XML PATH('');
```

This will put the generated string in an XML viewer. In the query options you must set the DataGrid XML output size to unlimited. This is a way to get almost any size back...

Comment: @Powellellogram Try to check the length with LEN ()

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. The inserted line breaks are not random. It just looks it due to the other (intended) line breaks. They don't show up in SQL Managment Studio's "XML Editor", but when you right click and save on the data, SQL Managment Studio inserts a `\r\n` after 2033 characters (awfully close to 2048). That seems to match what I was getting when just copy-pasting the "row" from the DataGrid into a text file. Setting the DataGrid XML output size from 2Mb to unlimited doesn't seem to fix this. Copy-paste from the "XML Editor" wasn't an option due to the large data size. "Results to text" and "Results to file" didn't help either.

I ended up replacing legitimate line breaks with ¶ and then replacing newlines with empty string, and ¶ back to new lines with regexs later when I actually wanted to use the XML as XML.

So, in sql:

`REPLACE(REPLACE([Value], CHAR(10), '¶'), char(13), '')`

then in javascript

`parseXML = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString( data.replace(/\r\n/g, "").replace(/¶/g,"\r\n"), "text/xml");`

Side note `CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Value] + ']]>' AS XML) [Value]` seems to remove the CDATA tag, and encode `[Value]` into xml. I was sorely confused when my CDATA tags disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today.

Try [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017%2Fsql%2Fazure-data-studio%2Fdownload&usg=AOvVaw1fCuJBVUlLfoKEdPLzSMcC) it does not have the same limitations as SSMS.

Works like a charm (at least on the built in preview}